# Резиновый сайт с помощью CSS и DIV

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Есть дизайн сайта, надо сделать резиновую верстку. Но эта верстка должна отвечать многим требованиям:

1. Сайт должен быть резиновым. Но крайне желательно ограничить размеры сайта шириной 1200 пикселей и минимальной шириной 860 пикселей.
2. В шапке сайта есть три рисунка. Нужно их позиционировать таким образом, чтобы рисунок слева оставался слева, рисунок справа оставался справа, а рисунок по центру находился по центру всегда, независимо от ширины монитора.

Подскажите, кто сталкивался с такими трудностями - как решить?

Answer (score 2):

Ограничение ширины (максимальная ширина и минимальная ширина) задаётся с помощью `max-widht, min-widht`. Ну а с картинками я вижу такое решение.

Так как ширина картирнок постоянна, то расположить их не так сложно. Пусть каждая картинка будет по `200px`. То есть общая ширина картинок будет равна `600px`. Общая ширина `860px`. Оставляем под контент, допустим, `600px`, а остальное пусть будет полями (то есть на каждое поле остаётся по `130px`). Ну и всё - левую картинку размещаем float: left к левому краю блока контента, вторую - float: right к правому краю. Центральной картинке задаём левое поле равное `margin-left: 200px;`.

Так как нужна резиновая вёрстка, то можно левое поле задать в процентах от ширины, которую занимает левая картинка относительно общей ширины страницы.

Comment: А можно просто сделать position:absolute;right:0px; -для правой и position:absolute;left:0px;-для левой и пишется min-with а не min-widht и также с max-with

Answer (score 0):

max/min-width/height довольно глючно себя ведут в разных браузерах. Относительное позиционирование и масштабирование в % Вам в помощь!

Comment: "Относительное позиционирование и масштабирование в % Вам в помощь!" - то есть? не очень понятно.

Comment: Тоисть, судя по всему ваших знаний не достаточно чтобы такое сделать.

Answer (score 0):

короче если у тебя есть обрамляющий тег сделай его в %. если нет сделай в свойствах у body.

Лучше всего делай не резиновую верстку, а гибридную, это смесь  резиновой и статичной.
Все сайты в основном сделаны на гибриде

Проценты помогают отобразить сайт в зависимости от внешних условий.(ширины экрана)
Для этого делай у дивов(которые не вложенные) width 100%, можешь сделать и у вложенных, это значит, что вложенный див покроет 100% всей ширины родительского дива.

Совет:  У вложенных используй лучше px.

В общем вот не много о процентах и пикселях

[Проценты и другие значения](http://htmlbook.ru/samcss/znacheniya-stilevykh-svoystv)

Не забывай также о позиционировании, это важно при резиновой или гибридной верстке

[Позиция](http://htmlbook.ru/css/position)